# How to convert an uneven tab separated file using sed?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

How to convert an uneven TAB separated input file to CSV or PSV using sed command?

```
28828082-1      04/08/19 08:48  04/11/19 12:37  04/12/19 16:22  4/15-4/16       04/17/19        2       9       LCO     W                       OIP     04/08/19 08:53 21       1       58.00           9       222     79      FEDX    FEDXH   SL3     484657064673    0410099900691041119             SMITHFIELD      RI      02917   "41.890066 , -71.548680"        YES
```

Above is 1 row, I tried using  `sed -r 's/^\s+//;s/\s+/|/g'` but the result was not as expected.

Comment: What did you expect? How was the result different to your expectation?

Answer (score 1):

`gawk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -vFPAT='([^[:space:]]+)|("[^"]+")' -v OFS='|' '$1=$1' file

28828082-1|04/08/19|08:48|04/11/19|12:37|04/12/19|16:22|4/15-4/16|04/17/19|2|9|LCO|W|OIP|04/08/19|08:53|21|1|58.00|9|222|79|FEDX|FEDXH|SL3|484657064673|0410099900691041119|SMITHFIELD|RI|02917|"41.890066 , -71.548680"|YES
```

define the field pattern as non space or a quoted value which might include spaces (but not escaped quotes), replace the output field separated with tab, force the line to be parsed and non zero lines will be printed after format change.

A better version would be `... '{$1=$1; print}'`.

Of course, if all the field delimiters are tabs and quotes string doesn't include any tabs, it's much simpler.

Comment: `A better version would be ... '{$1=$1; print}'` - FWIW I very strongly agree :-). You should only use the result of an action as a condition if you **need** it to be - see `echo '0 3' | awk '$1=$1'` vs `echo '0 3' | awk '{$1=$1}1'`

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ printf 'now\t"is the winter"\tof\t"our discontent"\n' > file
$ cat file
now     "is the winter" of      "our discontent"

$ tr '\t' ',' < file
now,"is the winter",of,"our discontent"

$ tr '\t' '|' < file
now|"is the winter"|of|"our discontent"
```

Answer (score 0):

You initial answer was very close:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/|/g' input.txt
```

#### Explanation:

`[[:space:]]` Match a single whitespace character such as space/tab/CR/newline.

`\+` Match one or more of the current grab.

#### Update:

If you require 2 or more white spaces.

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{2,\}/|/g' input.txt
```

`\{2,\}` Match two or more of the current grab.

Comment: That would convert `"41.890066 , -71.548680"` to `"41.890066|,|-71.548680"` which I'd be surprised is desirable but since the OP hasn't posted the expected output we're all just guessing.

Comment: You're welcome but I suspect the real solution is to not modify any spaces within double quotes (if we're assuming as in your answer that the OP wants all spaces between "fields" converted to pipes rather than just converting tabs).